# Tomcat, UTF-8, and non-bmp characters

Tags: tomcat, utf-8, url-encoding, astral-plane

I am running a GWT-based web application on Tomcat 6.0.32.

I am having trouble getting URLs that contain non-BMP characters (where these characters live in filenames) to work.  Any URLs that contain characters of 3-bytes or less function without a problem.

For example:
The file name is .txt - when URL encoded as UTF-8 it is %F0%A5%A7%84.txt

`http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/%F0%A5%A7%84.txt?param1=x&param2=y` that particular view is unable to be found

However if the file name is 犬.txt - when URL encoded as UTF-8 it is %E7%8A%AC.txt -

`http://localhost:8080/foo/bar/%E7%8A%AC.txt?param1=x&param2=y` the view is correctly located.

I have server.xml set in Tomcat to use URIEncoding=UTF-8 on a Windows XP machine.

Does anyone know of any current limitations in Tomcat 6 with respect to the decoding of non-BMP characters?

Comment: FYI: I can't reproduce your problem on Tomcat 7.0.19 nor Tomcat 6.0.20. Perhaps it's OS platform or environment specific? I'm using Win7 x64. I've created and saved files using Eclipse Helios SR2 whose workspace encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: I'm starting to guess it's platform specific.  Windows XP doesn't seem to have great support for non-bmp (4-byte) characters - I still can't get my WindowsXP-Japan to display them even though I have the proper fonts loaded.  I'm hoping to try to see if Windows 7 gives me better luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There was some work quite a few years ago to address the remaining encoding issues (back in the Tomcat 4 days) so all current Tomcat versions should correctly handle decoding of any UTF-8 characters providing that URIEncoding="UTF-8" is set on the connector.

If it doesn't then the possible causes (in order of likelihood are):
- Tomcat configuration issue (it looks like you have this sorted)
- application issue
- OS / file system configuration / issue
- Tomcat bug

If you are sure it is a Tomcat bug, please report it and someone will take a look.